# WSO2: JWTConfiguration not working for multi tenancy

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, wso2-api-manager, wso2

We have enabled the `EnableJWTGeneration` in `api-manager.xml`and its works fine for super tenant only.

**Problem**

Whenever our server receives a request from tenant users then WSO-APIM does't inject `JWTHeader`. It never adds the required header on the given request hence we are unable to test the multi tenancy support and are stuck in this point. We have followed the [Passing Enduser Attributes to the Backend Using JWT](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT) and [HOW TO USE JWT TOKENS TO EXCHANGE DATA](https://www.chakray.com/wso2-api-jwt-tokens-to-exchange-data/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed some strange behavior, `WSO2` doesn't have the required `Keystore/Jks` file for Tenants for key generation. Updating required keystore solved the problem.

For quick reference use this link to [generate new keystore file for tenants](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/11/05/how-to-changing-the-primary-keystore-of-a-tenant-in-carbon-products/).